# JavaScript - Prevent users from copy pasting a special character in input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, events, input

In `javascript` how can i check if the users have `'='` in the `text` they are pasting and prevent the `text` from being pasted in `textbox`. I found it a bit tricky. I am working on a vulnerability issue where users should not be allowed to enter `=` in `input` field where i have achieved to some extent where user cant enter in textfield but can copy paste which is an issue. Below is my code. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    inPutCheckForText();
 });

function inPutCheckForText()
{
    fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (index = 0; index < fields.length; ++index) 
    {
        fields[index].addEventListener("keydown", function(event) 
        {
            if (event.keyCode === 187) 
            {
                console.log("blocked.");
              event.preventDefault();
              return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `keydown ` listen to `change` event. In the callback see if you have `=` in your value, if you do remove it

Comment: To strip specific chars from pasted text, you could set a handler for the paste-event (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event), but this will not fix your vulnerability! A script could still insert those chars. You need to validate the input-data when you use it. NEVER trust any data from a source that unknowns have access to.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this:

```
<input type="text" onpaste="validatePaste(this, event)">
```

, and I call my function located inside `<script>` tags like:

```
function validatePaste(el, e) {
  var regex = /^[a-z .'-]+$/gi;
  var key = e.clipboardData.getData('text')
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to "keydown" event. you should use "paste" event to handle copy paste

```
$('#textbox').on("paste", function(e) {
  if (event.keyCode === 187) 
  {
    console.log("blocked.");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

or try using

```
$ ('#textbox').bind("paste", function (e) {
  if (event.keyCode === 187) 
  {
    console.log("blocked.");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: why two events, when we can use `change` event to handle both scenarios

Comment: preventDefault() is not working as expected in the 'change' event. while using 'change' the event will be triggered only after the text was pasted into the text box. but the requirement is to restrict pasting of the special character. so I have recommended using the 'paste' event.

Answer (score 0):

This will Work of Past event only, you can change it for other events. It will restrict a user to  Past '='  in the input field

```
$(function(){
        $("#textInput").bind('paste', function(e) {
        var ctl = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            //Do whatever you want to $(ctl) here....
            var bla = $('#textInput').val();
            if (bla.indexOf('=') > -1){
               alert("= not allowed");
                $( '#textInput' ).val(null) ;
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }, 100);
        });


    });
```